# Understanding why Minkowski’s inequality doesn't hold true for $0 < p < 1$?

Tags: functional-analysis, inequality

The triangle inequality given by

**$\left(\sum_{i=1}^n |x_i+y_i|^p\right)^{1/p}\leq \left(\sum_{i=1}^n |x_i|^p\right)^{1/p} + \left(\sum_{i=1}^n |y_i|^p\right)^{1/p}$**

is known as “Minkowski’s inequality" which holds true for $1\leq p <\infty$ while for $0 < p < 1$ it doesn't  hold.

Searching through net I have found that  **this inequality holds for $1\leq p <\infty$  is related to the observation that for such $p$ the function $x \to x^p$ for $x \geq 0$ is convex.**

**The failure of the triangle inequality is related to the observation that for $0 <
p < 1$,the function $x \to x^p$ for $x \geq 0$ is not convex.**

I am not able to understand these points. Could anybody explain me?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A function $h(x)$ is convex if it satisfies

$$h\left ( \alpha x_1 + (1-\alpha)x_2 \right) \le \alpha h(x_1) + (1-\alpha)h(x_2),
\quad\alpha\in [0,1]\tag{1}$$

Geometrically this means that for $x_1\le x\le x_2$ the graph of $h(x)$ must lie under the line connecting the points $h(x_1)$ and $h(x_2)$. Inspecting the graph of $h(x)=x^p$ it is easy to see that the function $x^p$ is convex for $p\ge 1$, but not for $0<p<1$.

In the [proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_inequality#Proof) of Minkowski's inequality they make use of exactly this fact. The proof starts by proving that the sum of some functions $f$ and $g$ has finite $p$-norm if both $f$ and $g$ do. We get

$$\left | \frac{f}{2}+\frac{g}{2}\right |^p\le
\left | \frac{|f|}{2}+\frac{|g|}{2}\right |^p$$

This inequality has nothing to do with convexity but only follows from taking the magnitudes of $f$ and $g$. In the following step, however, we make use of convexity:

$$\left | \frac{|f|}{2}+\frac{|g|}{2}\right |^p\le
\frac{|f|^p}{2}+\frac{|g|^p}{2}$$

Here we made use of (1) with $\alpha=1/2$ and $h(x)=x^p$, $p\ge 1$.
The rest of the proof builds on this result, that's why convexity (and therefore $p\ge 1$) is necessary for Minkowsi's inequality to hold.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Now things are clear to me. :)

Answer (score 0):

I have a good(well, I think it's good) interpretation. The Minkowski's inequality simply suggests that $L^p$ is a normed space. But you can show that $L^p$ isn't even locally convex space if $0<p<1$.

Comment: Isn't this just yet another reformulation of what OP didn't understand?

Comment: @lee Thanks for the reply . I need little more detail what you want to say.

Comment: Ah... Sorry... I think I have to say something about the detail. First we see that you only have to show that there exists functions f and g, with their 'p-norm' equal to 1, yet their convex combination may have 'p-norm' bigger than 1. Hint: take f=x and g=1 and the set U=[0,1]. Hope this comment can help you.